# AWS How to re-schedule a S3 lambda event?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a lambda which runs when a object is created in S3, in some cases I need to reschedule this lambda to happen lets say 15 minutes later.

When my lambda runs by second time I need to have the same event argument, I dont mind about other fields than the bucket and path.
`event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name` `event.Records[0].s3.object.key` . But it is easy to have same `event`

My alternative is to save that data in dynamo and have another lambda which will read from there each 15 minutes (awful).

But it will be nicer to just reschedule my current function and pass same arguments to it.
Something like this:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
   if(xyz)
      reschedule(15 * 1000 * 60, 'ThisLambdaName', event, context); 
}
```

Something like setTimeout but without AWS charging me for those 15 minutes lol.

Answer (score 5):

You can use DynamoDB with [TTL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/TTL.html), DynamoDB Streams and AWS Lambda for this.

Save the data in DynamoDB and set the TTL to 15 minutes after.

When the TTL is reached for an item, it will create a DynamoDB Stream which you can then use to trigger the original function again with the original data. You most likely have to make some changes in your handler to address events from S3 and DynamoDB Streams differently.

References:

- [DynamoDB Streams and Time To Live](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/time-to-live-ttl-streams.html)
- [DynamoDB Streams and AWS Lambda Triggers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html)

Comment: Thanks  for your answer, I was hopping there is an alternative to use Dynamo or save the data by myself  and do it more straight forward, but seems no way.

Comment: There is. But you will have to actively check it (e.g. every 15 minutes) like you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but the currently only answer is misleading. Leveraging DynamoDB with TTL isn't good because according to [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/howitworks-ttl.html) it could take up to 48 hours before an expired item is removed, so depending on the use case, the lambda function might execute a couple of days late.

There are a couple of simple solutions available.

1) In your lambda function that's triggered by S3, put the event on an [SQS delay queue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-delay-queues.html). Note that the maximum delay before the message becomes available is 15 minutes.

2) In your S3 triggered lambda function, use the [CloudWatch Events PutRule API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchEvents/latest/APIReference/API_PutRule.html) and create a rule that executes a lambda function at a given time. Make sure to [delete the rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchEvents/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteRule.html) once it's been processed since the soft limit is 100 rules per region.

Comment: Your first option sounds cool, although the maximum delay is only 15 minutes. Thanks!

Comment: Just for the shake, I implemented the dynamoDB with TTL solution, most of the time is working fine without the possible delays.